# Problem freeing memory (subject Template)

Tags: c++, templates

Set.h

```
#ifndef Set_h
#define Set_h

#include <iostream>
using namespace::std;

template <class T>
class Set {
    T* group;
    int size_group;
public:
    Set():group(NULL),size_group(0){};
    Set(T*,int);
    Set(const Set<T>&);
    ~Set();


    bool isThere(const T&)const;
    void getType()const;

    Set<T>& operator =(const Set<T>&);
    bool operator ==(const Set<T>&) const;
    void operator +=(const T);
    void operator -=(const T&);
    Set<T>& operator +(Set<T>&);
    Set<T>& operator -(const Set<T>&);
    bool operator >(const Set<T>&)const;
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream&,const Set<T>&);

};

//Realizations

template <class T>
Set<T>::Set(T* gro,int size):group(gro),size_group(size){}

template <class T>
Set<T>::Set(const Set<T>& obj){ // c'Ctor (copy)
    this->size_group = obj.size_group;
    this->group = new T[this->size_group];
    for (int i = 0; i < size_group; i++) {
        group[i] = obj.group[i];
    }
}

template <class T>
void Set<T>::getType() const{
    cout << "The type is: " << typeid(group).name() << endl;
}

template <class T>
Set<T>& Set<T>::operator = (const Set<T>& obj){
    this->size_group = obj.size_group;
    this->group = new T[size_group];
    for (int i = 0; i < size_group; i++) {
        this->group[i] = obj.group[i];
    }
    return *this;
}

template <class T>
bool Set<T>::operator==(const Set<T>& obj) const{
    int count = 0;
    T temp;
    if(this->size_group != obj.size_group)
        return false;
    for (int i = 0; this->size_group; i++) {
        temp = this->group[i];
        count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < obj.size_group; j++) {
            if(temp == obj.group[j])
                count++;
        }
        if(count != 1)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

template <class T>
void Set<T>::operator+=(const T var){
    if(!isThere(var)){
        T* Temp = new T[this->size_group+1];
        for (int i = 0; i < this->size_group; i++)
            Temp[i] = this->group[i];
        Temp[size_group] = var;
        delete [] this->group;
        this->size_group++;
        this->group = Temp;
    }

}

template <class T>
Set<T>& Set<T>::operator+(Set<T>& obj){ //
    if(obj.size_group > this->size_group){
        for (int i = 0; i < obj.size_group; i++){
            for (int j = 0 ; j < this->size_group; j++){
                if(!this->isThere(obj.group[i]))
                    *this += obj.group[i];
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }else{
        for (int i = 0; i < this->size_group; i++){
            for (int j = 0 ; j < obj.size_group; j++){
                if(!obj.isThere(this->group[i]))
                    obj += this->group[i];
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }
}


template <class T>
bool Set<T>::isThere(const T& var) const{
    for (int i = 0; i < this->size_group; i++) {
        if(this->group[i] == var)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}




template <class T>
Set<T>::~Set() {
    delete [] group;
}

#endif /* Set_h */
```

Main:

```
#include "Set.h"

int main() {
    int arr[] = {3,7,8,1};
    int arr2[] = {1,2,5};

    Set<int> j(arr,4),l(arr2,3),k;

    k = j + l;
}
```

I'm trying to merge two arrays, but my problem is with the method `void Set<T>::operator+=(const T var)` and this line `delete [] this-> group;`

I get this error:

```
Template & Exception (8421,0x1000dadc0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7ffeefbff400: pointer being Friday was not allocated
Template & Exception (8421,0x1000dadc0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Comment: So if I understood you correctly, should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Your `Set(T*,int)` constructor is not allocating `new[]`'ed memory for `group` to point at, which means `operator+=` (and `~Set()`, and `operator=`) will fail at runtime when they try to `delete[]` the memory that `group` points at, which in your example is local stack memory that `main()` owns and passes in to the `j` and `l` objects.

Your `Set(T*,int)` constructor must `new[]` the `group` array and copy the contents of the input `gro` array into it, similar to how your copy constructor does, eg:

```
template <class T>
Set<T>::Set(T* gro, int size) : group(NULL), size_group(0)
{
    size_group = size;
    group = new T[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        group[i] = gro[i];
    }
}
```

---

On a side note, your `operator=` is leaking memory, as it does not `delete[]` the current `group` array before assigning a new `group` array.  It should be making a temporary array, similar to how your `operator+=` does, eg:

```
template <class T>
Set<T>& Set<T>::operator=(const Set<T>& obj)
{
    if (this != &obj){
        T* Temp = new T[obj.size_group];
        for (int i = 0; i < obj.size_group; i++)
            Temp[i] = obj.group[i];
        delete [] group;
        group = Temp;
        size_group = obj.size_group;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Or better, use your copy constructor via the [copy-swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/) instead:

```
template <class T>
Set<T>& Set<T>::operator=(const Set<T>& obj)
{
    if (this != &obj){
        Set<T> temp(obj);
        std::swap(group, temp.group);
        std::swap(size_group, temp.size_group);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Also, your `operator+` is implemented all wrong.  It needs to return a new `Set` that is the concatenation of the arrays of `*this` and `obj`, not modify `obj` or `*this` at all.  As such, it needs to look more like this instead:

```
template <class T>
Set<T> Set<T>::operator+(const Set<T>& obj) const
{
    Set<T> res(*this);
    for (int i = 0; i < obj.size_group; i++) {
        res += obj.group[i];
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: ok i understand why...but i send the address of arr[] from the main to my T* group 
why i should allocating new memory? can you explain to me please?

Comment: @RoniJackVituli Because the rest of your `Set` class *expects* `group` to *ALWAYS* be pointing at `new[]`'ed memory. But you are not doing that in the `Set(T*,int)` constructor, which is what `main()` calls. So you get a runtime error when `delete[]` is called on memory that is owned by the local stack in `main()`. You can't just point `group` at whatever random memory the caller passes in. `Set` needs to be the one that allocates the memory that `group` points to.

Comment: @RoniJackVituli The other scenario is if the user passed you `int *p = new int(0); Set<int>(p, 1)`.  Your destructor would then erroneously call `delete [] group;` when the memory was not allocated using `new[]`, but with simply `new`, thus the wrong form of `delete` would have been used.  In other words, the `Set` class has no idea where that pointer that it gets comes from.